# J2EE reflection class

Tags: class, jakarta-ee, reflection, loader

I am using reflection to call the constructor of a class called Child which requires the package: org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils
I've added it to the class path and have been using it else where just fine, but reflection does not seem to see my class path.

Error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils

I've searched and seen lots of writing about class loader but I still do not understand this. Could someone please explain the problem and how to solve it as clearly as possible?

```
//main class:
try {
   Class<?> claz = Class.forName(claz_str);
   Parent p = (Parent) claz.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class, String[].class, String[].class).newInstance(elmName, nodes_arr, params_arr);
   } catch (Exception e) {
   throw new Exception(e.getCause());
}

// Child.class
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;
public class Child extends Parent{
   public Child(){
      if(!ArrayUtils.contains(NUM_OF_PARAMS, 2)){ // <<====== run time error
        System.out.println("stuff")
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems OK. Are you providing full qualify name of your class as `claz_str`.
It should be

```
claz_str = "com.package.Class";
```

Hope solve your problem.